# Is an offer letter by email sufficient or are signatures necessary?

Tags: job-offer, resignation

When in college, I got selected via campus recruitment and the company sent me an offer letter by email, to which I replied, because I knew this was a trusted source. On the joining day, they gave my appointment letter which they and I signed.

Now, after 8 years in this company, I've been interviewed and selected by a startup. They have sent me an offer letter (pdf form) by email. The people are very mature, polite and they even gave me proof of their company registration when I asked for it. They are even willing to sign the offer letter for me, and I have the option of either taking half a day leave tomorrow to collect the signed offer letter or I can just reply by email, that I accept the job offer. They have verbally assured me that even if the formality of signing the offer letter is not done, they will honour the fact that I have been offered the job.

So is it really necessary/safer to get signatures on the offer letter or does an email (it was sent from their domain id) from them and a reply from me form a proper legal agreement that the job was offered and accepted, and that I can now formally resign from my current job?

Comment: I have resigned more than once on written confirmation of a job offer in an email, then let the signed version catch up.  Of course there is perhaps more risk to go on the email, but it depends on your level of trust with the employer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I felt everything is above board I would probably take them at their word and save myself half a day if I had pressing issues to deal with. I see no reason from what you have said that would make me concerned.

If I had any concerns at all I would take the half day off and go check out my new workplace while picking up the documents. And I might well do that in any case just to have a look and say hello.

In answer to your question I think you can safely resign on the strength of the email without getting the signed document first.

Comment: Completely agree :)